# Find the caller stack of a TF C++ function called in Python

Tags: tensorflow

I am working with the Python version of Tensorflow wrapping the C++ code.

I am looking for a way to, for a given C++ function in Tensorflow, find how to trace all the caller functions starting from Python functions to c++ functions that made that call (Swig is transparent).

I read about mixed language debugging but the problem is that I don't know the called path of C++ functions to put breakpoints. If I know it, the problem is solved from the beginning and I won't ask this question.

Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my general strategy for debugging/inspecting TensorFlow.

#### Compile and install

First, make sure you compile it with debugging enabled. Here is one of the scripts that I use:

```
#!/bin/bash
export CC_OPT_FLAGS="-march=native"
export GCC_HOST_COMPILER_PATH=/usr/bin/gcc
export TF_NEED_GCP=0
export TF_NEED_GDR=0
export TF_NEED_S3=0
export TF_NEED_HDFS=0
export TF_NEED_MKL=0
export TF_NEED_MPI=0
export TF_NEED_OPENCL=0
export TF_NEED_CUDA=0
export TF_ENABLE_XLA=1
export TF_NEED_JEMALLOC=1
export TF_NEED_VERBS=0

TF_NEED_CUDA=0 bazel clean --expunge_async
PYTHON_LIB_PATH=${PYTHON_LIB_PATH} \
PYTHON_BIN_PATH=${PYTHON_BIN_PATH} ./configure 

bazel build -c dbg --copt=-msse4.2 //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package && \
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/pkg
pip install /tmp/pkg/*.whl
```

#### Create a test program

Now craft a small Python program to run. Make sure to enable device placement logging. This gives some good information.

```
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.core.protobuf import config_pb2

config = config_pb2.ConfigProto()
config.log_device_placement = True

ar = []
ar.append(np.array(
    [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    dtype='f'))
ar.append(np.array(
    [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    dtype='f'))
ar.append(np.array(
    [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    dtype='f'))

sess = tf.Session(graph=None, config=config)
with sess.graph.as_default(), sess.as_default():
    with sess.graph.device('/device:CPU:0'):
        c = tf.add_n(ar)
        print(sess.run(c))
```

#### Run #1

When TensorFlow is built and is installed, be sure to turn up the output and run the Python script:

```
export TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=0
python my_tf_program.py
```

This should give you some good output. Something like:

```
2017-10-20 16:47:47.194105: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX
 AVX2 FMA
2017-10-20 16:47:49.354363: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:299] Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0 -> device: XLA_CPU device

2017-10-20 16:47:49.358699: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:874] AddN: (AddN)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2017-10-20 16:47:49.358766: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:874] Const_2: (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2017-10-20 16:47:49.358806: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:874] Const_1: (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2017-10-20 16:47:49.358842: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:874] Const: (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
[ 3.  3.  3.  3.  3.]
Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0 -> device: XLA_CPU device
AddN: (AddN): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Const_2: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Const_1: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Const: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
```

You have a hint! It looks like AddN is being called. Let's go find it in the code:

```
[smckenney@xxx tensorflow (develop)]$ grep -nr "\"AddN\"" tensorflow/core/kernels/* | grep REGISTER
tensorflow/core/kernels/aggregate_ops.cc:237:REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("AddN")
tensorflow/core/kernels/aggregate_ops.cc:246:REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("AddN")
tensorflow/core/kernels/aggregate_ops.cc:262:REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("AddN")
```

After peeking in aggregate_ops.cc, an AddN class will exist with a Compute() method. This is where the breakpoint goes:

```
41  template <typename Device, typename T>
42  class AddNOp : public OpKernel {
43   public:
44    explicit AddNOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context) {}
45
46    void Compute(OpKernelContext* ctx) override {
47      if (!ctx->ValidateInputsAreSameShape(this)) return;
48
49      const Tensor& input0 = ctx->input(0);
```

#### Debug the TensorFlow program

Now you have all of the information you need. Run the python script again in a debugger and set a breakpoint at aggregate_ops.cc line 47:

```
(tf-runner) spmckenney@host:/scratch/bitbucket$ lldb -- python my_tf_program.py
(lldb) target create "python"
Current executable set to 'python' (x86_64).
(lldb) settings set -- target.run-args  "/scratch/bitbucket/tmp/so_answer.py"
(lldb) b aggregate_ops.cc:47
Breakpoint 1: no locations (pending).
WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.
(lldb) run
```

You may have to cont'inue a few times as lldb is loading symbols. After that, the breakpoint gets hit and you get your backtrace:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 38544, 0x00007fff72f4875d _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so`tensorflow::AddNOp<Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice, float>::Compute(this=0x00000000013a0150, ctx=0x0
0007fffffff9750) + 49 at aggregate_ops.cc:47, name = 'python', stop reason = breakpoint 1.6
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff72f4875d _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so`tensorflow::AddNOp<Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice, float>::Compute(this=0x00000000013a0150, ctx=0x00007fffffff9
750) + 49 at aggregate_ops.cc:47
    frame #1: 0x00007fff734844d1 _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so`tensorflow::grappler::ConstantFolding::EvaluateNode(this=0x0000000001419320, node=0x000000000144dad0, in
puts=0x00007fffffff9d10, output=0x00007fffffff9d60) const + 731 at constant_folding.cc:407
    frame #2: 0x00007fff73484b9b _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so`tensorflow::grappler::ConstantFolding::EvaluateOneFoldable(this=0x0000000001419320, node=0x000000000144d
ad0, outputs=0x00007fffffff9f90) + 1079 at constant_folding.cc:448

--- snip ---

    frame #17: 0x00007fff6f7e1b6b _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so`tensorflow::TF_Run_wrapper(session=0x000000000144cae0, run_options=0x0000000000000000, feed_dict=0x0000
7fffdf7afd88, output_names=0x00007fffffffd0b0, target_nodes=0x00007fffffffd100, out_status=0x0000000001840aa0, out_values=0x00007fffffffd150, run_outputs=0x000000000000
0000) + 97 at tf_session_helper.cc:149
    frame #18: 0x00007fff6f76d84c _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so`::_wrap_TF_Run((null)=0x00007fff7e1ed138, args=0x00007fffd5823458) + 2835 at pywrap_tensorflow_internal
.cc:15057
    frame #19: 0x00000000004866fb python`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 1099
    frame #20: 0x000000000048f2df python`___lldb_unnamed_symbol1826$$python + 383
    frame #21: 0x00000000004f14fa python`PyObject_Call + 58
    frame #22: 0x0000000000488252 python`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 8098
    frame #23: 0x000000000048e45b python`PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 347
    frame #24: 0x000000000048a673 python`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 17347
    frame #25: 0x000000000048e45b python`PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 347
    frame #26: 0x000000000048a673 python`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 17347
    frame #27: 0x000000000048a19d python`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 16109
    frame #28: 0x000000000048e45b python`PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 347
    frame #29: 0x000000000048a673 python`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 17347
    frame #30: 0x000000000048e45b python`PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 347
    frame #31: 0x000000000048f15b python`PyEval_EvalCode + 59
    frame #32: 0x0000000000559730 python`___lldb_unnamed_symbol2877$$python + 48
    frame #33: 0x00000000004793c5 python`PyRun_FileExFlags + 167
    frame #34: 0x00000000004797a2 python`PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 872
    frame #35: 0x00000000005bfaa0 python`Py_Main + 1280
    frame #36: 0x000000000047d9f4 python`main + 308
    frame #37: 0x00007ffff7814f45 libc.so.6`__libc_start_main(main=(python`main), argc=2, argv=0x00007fffffffe138, init=<unavailable>, fini=<unavailable>, rtld_fini=<un
available>, stack_end=0x00007fffffffe128) + 245 at libc-start.c:287
    frame #38: 0x000000000056d585 python`_start + 41
```

I'm not interested in the Python backtrace as much for what I am working on, but I imagine it isn't that hard to get the full Python trace as well instead of locations.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your C function is getting called through `TF_Run` call on Python side. To get Python side of backtrace, use pdb:

edit `session.py` on your system and add `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` right before any invocation of `TF_Run`. To find `session.py` go to location of your TF distro (`python -c "import tensorflow as tf; import inspect; print(inspect.getsourcefile(tf).rsplit('/',1)[0])"`) and search for `session.py` file.

That drops you into `pdb` prompt and you can do `bt` to get backtrace.

To get C++ side of backtrace, use gdb.

```
gdb python
run myscript.py
```

Use `gdb` command to set breakpoints inside C files and `bt` to get backtrace. You get better results if you use a debug build of tensorflow -- https://github.com/mind/wheels/releases/tag/tf1.3.1-cpu-debug

Comment: I found the following class that gives the caller stack from Python to C++ as if swig is transparent: https://panthema.net/2008/0901-stacktrace-demangled/